# For Loop doesn't render components probably

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

The problem i'm facing is i want a component to be rendered as much as i assign in for loops,
in this example 5 times,

```
for (var k = 0; k <= 5; k++) {
      return(
           <div>Hi</div>
      )
}
```

But it only renders it once, any thoughts?

Comment: Your `return` *exits* the loop. You need to collect all and return them all after the loop

Comment: and how can i do that?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, are you trying to add the div to the DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of list and keys in react . Please have try like this

```
const list = Array(5).fill("Hi")
const elems = list.map((item ,i) => {
    return <div key={i}>{item}</div>
})

display elems in your template like this

{elems}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is exiting as soon as it encounters the return statement. You need to return all values that you want to render for it to work. Instead of a for loop a `map` works better here as `map` returns a new array.

You could do something like this:

```
{
    Array(5).fill('Hi').map((item, i) => <div key={i}>{item}</div>
}
```

Here first i'm creating an array of 5 items using `Array(5)`. Then filling all values with `Hi`. Then using the map on the array to iterate and return a div for every entry in the array.

In react you need to add keys when creating lists of elements. "key" is a special string attribute you need to include for the repeating elements. You can learn more about that here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a for loop to render jsx, you have to use a map like this:

```
{Array(5).fill(0).map((_, i) => <div key={i}>Hi</div>)}
```